# Enable/Disable button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a project where if someone is "on call" then the button to remove that individual needs to be disabled.   I understand that I need to do something like

```
button.Enabled = false
```

However, I am having problems accessing my button in my VB.NET code.  I can access other buttons, but not this particular one.

In my aspx code the code for the button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
```

When I try to do btnRemove.Enabled it isn't shown on the options with Intellisense, and basically isn't recognized.  I thought that having the runat="server" was sufficient to get access to it.  Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Rename it, save, rename it back to `btnRemove`, save. Then try again. Where is this button, you can access it directly only if it's on top of the page.

Comment: I did try this, came up with the same issue of not finding that specific button

Comment: Is there a [file].designer.vb? What version of asp.net are you using? Is AutoEventWireup="False" or "True"?

Comment: AutoEventWireup is set to false.  I do not see the file.designer.vb.  I'm using the 4.5 .NET framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Right click on yourFile.aspx.designer.vb and select delete.
2. Right click on yourFile.aspx and select (Convert to Web Application).
3. Click OK to the pop-up message that will appear.